# youtube output on my app without using a standard browser with webview

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I want to put the webversion of youtube in my application where you can do everything(like watch and search videos,..) without using a standard browser. I have written this code but every time pop ups which browser I want to use (like Google chrome,..)but I want to let it display on my appscreen and I have set the permission of internet already.

here the code:

youtube.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

youtube.java:

```
package com.example.listentomusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Youtube extends Activity {

    public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your CustomWebViewClient & set it to your webView.

Like this -

```
 private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Now set this `CustomeWebViewClient` to your `webView`-

```
    WV.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Also `main(String[] args)` is of no use, remove it.